# Hazard and NIOSH Code and Information for Prescription Drugs

Tags: openfda

Is there an API endpoint via OpenFDA or some other source that will give me Hazard and NIOSH codes for a specific drug based on an NDC number or some other code?

For example, the drug WARFARIN SODIUM- warfarin tablet has a NIOSH code of NT3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no endpoint which includes that implements these codes. My apologies for the very delayed reply.